# Insert data in sqlite Database after the end of call

Tags: android, sqlite

I have developed an app in android to record all call history. In my apps call records are inserted only when user run my app. But I want to insert call records after the end of each call. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about services for that. Refer to this [document on Android Developers guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). Also, you can find tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html), that will let you understand how you can invoke a service.

And to recognize when the call ends, you may refer to this [document](http://androidapps.org.ua/i_sect18_d1e18123.html).